# Problems with bundled gems and datamapper: conflict with muti_json version?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rvm, bundler, datamapper

I have a site running with nginx/unicorn/sinatra (bundler/rvm).
After my last `bundle update`, I am getting an error:

```
in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate dm-serializer-1.2.1, because multi_json-1.3.5 conflicts with multi_json (~> 1.0.3)
```

My Gemfile is:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem 'unicorn'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'datamapper'
gem 'dm-mysql-adapter'
gem 'haml'
gem 'sass'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
```

Gemfile.lock does not have any reference to multi_json 1.0.3

Any ideas?

Comment: the problem was with omniauth-twitter vs dm-serializer trying to lock different versions of multi_json. Uninstalling last version of omniauth-tewiter and locking its version to 0.0.9 helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was:

- check Gemfile.lock to see which gem(s) bring in later version (in this case - omniauth-twitter)
- Find a version of 'offender' that does not require too high version
- Rollback later versions, lock to a proper version in Gemfile

In this particular case, Gemfile that works needed lines:

```
gem 'omniauth-twitter', '0.0.9'
gem 'multi_json', '~> 1.0.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the gems in your bundle has an older version of `multi_json` as a dependency it looks like. See if `bundle viz` tells you. You'll need to install the `ruby-graphviz` gem and graphviz itself if you don't have them installed already, though.

Another way to see what's up is to add `multi_json` to your gemfile at the version you're trying to upgrade to, then do a `bundle install` and see what errors come out.

Comment: I am not trying to install any version of multi_json, it is a dependency. Attempts to enforce any version do not help, error stays.

Comment: I understand that. What I'm trying to do is find out what gem is using 1.0.3.

Comment: This is dm-serializer explicit dependency. What I do not understand, is that locking multi_json to 1.0.3 gives the same error (no reference to higher versions in Gemfile.lock)

Comment: Something is requiring multi_json 1.0.3. [It isn't dm-serializer, though](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-serializer/blob/master/dm-serializer.gemspec). dm-serializer wants to use a newer version, but cannot because something else is requiring the old one. What is requiring the old version of multi_json? Thats what you need to find out.

Comment: You pointed to the latest beta version of dm-serializer that is not brought in by default (this dependency is updated just 19 days ago)

Comment: Also, version of datamepper it refers to, (~> 1.3.0.beta), is not accessible

Answer (score 0):

This is how to fix this problem:

```
rvm uninstall multi_json
```

It will tell you that you have many versions installed, show you a list of them, and ask you which one exactly you want to uninstall.
Try the first one, if it tells you that it is used by some other gem, try the second one, and so on. Keep deleting all the unused versions until only one remains.

This is how I do it, but there may be some *clearner* solution. If anyone knows it, thanks for sharing it with us.